# How to emit an event within a NoRowsOverlayComponent?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to display an overlay container which includes a button. When the button get clicked an event should be propagted to the parent component. In my research I found that there **was** the option to set 'noRowsOverlayComponentParams' which isn't present in my version(22.1.2). I am also not able to get the click event of the button.

Is there a workaround or a setting which solves my problem?

PS: The component is shown right but I can't get the click event.

**Grid-Options:**

```
let options: any = {
      defaultColDef: {
        sortable: true,
        filter: true,
        resizable: true
      },
      suppressPaginationPanel: true,
      columnDefs: [...],
      paginationPageSize: 10,
      context: { componentParent: this},
      domLayout: 'normal',
      enableCellTextSelection: true,
      autoSizePadding: 2,
      noRowsOverlayComponent: 'myNoRowsComponent',
      frameworkComponents: {
        myNoRowsComponent: MyNoRowsComponent
      }
    };
```

**MyNoRowsComponent.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { INoRowsOverlayAngularComp } from '@ag-grid-community/angular';
import { INoRowsOverlayParams, IAfterGuiAttachedParams } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-no-rows',
  templateUrl: './my-no-rows.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-no-rows.component.scss']
})
export class MyNoRowsComponent implements INoRowsOverlayAngularComp {

  params: any;

  agInit(params: INoRowsOverlayParams): void {
    this.params = params;

  }

  clickImport() {
    // this.params.context.componentParent.clickButton(); // <-- here I want to emit an event
  }

  afterGuiAttached?(params?: IAfterGuiAttachedParams): void { }

}
```

**MyNoRowsComponent.html:**

```
<button (click)="clickImport()">My Button</Button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who searching this problem, I have found that pointer-events set as disabled for overlays.
simply add this to your button class:

```
pointer-events: all;
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thx

Answer (score -1):

I would create a shared service, that is injected into both the parent component and the overlay component.

The shared service could expose a 'notify' method, which calls next on a Subject. 
It could also expose a 'getNotifications' that returns the Subject as an Observable.

Then the parent component can subscribe to the Observable,
and the overlay can call the 'notify' method, to communicate data to the parent component.

Comment: I know that but the problem is I can't even get the click-event from the button (the click function will be never triggered -> I have tested and debugged it).

Comment: @JuNe have you found a way? i'm also trying this exact same scenario

Comment: @GillesVercammen no currently not. We have removed the button for now in our application because it has not a high priority for us. Maybe we will try it with a newer version later.